# Hide text on SPAN tag based on Class and Title

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to hide the content inside a `<span>` tag, but with a specific text:

```
<span class="ms-RadioText" title="Created / Criar"><input id="ctl00_m_g_178a35bf_4d92_4887_8b39_b6e6e11d4a09_ff21_ctl00_ctl00" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_178a35bf_4d92_4887_8b39_b6e6e11d4a09$ff21$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl00" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_178a35bf_4d92_4887_8b39_b6e6e11d4a09_ff21_ctl00_ctl00">Created / Criar</label></span>
<span class="ms-RadioText" title="Change / Alterar"><input id="ctl00_m_g_178a35bf_4d92_4887_8b39_b6e6e11d4a09_ff21_ctl00_ctl01" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_178a35bf_4d92_4887_8b39_b6e6e11d4a09$ff21$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl01" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_178a35bf_4d92_4887_8b39_b6e6e11d4a09_ff21_ctl00_ctl01">Change / Alterar</label></span>
```

I must hide the content of class "ms-RadioText" and title tag "Created / Criar"

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS solution?

Comment: Are you looking for "Created / Criar" in the title **attribute** or the label **tag**?

Answer (score 2):

so just target that element then :

```
$('span.ms-RadioText[title="Created / Criar"]').hide();
```

note: the attributes selector works in CSS3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //This removes it from the page
 $('span.ms-RadioText[title="Created / Criar"]').hide();  

 //same as above
 $('span.ms-RadioText[title="Created / Criar"]').css('display', 'none'); 

 //This makes it invisible, but it still exists in document flow
 $('span.ms-RadioText[title="Created / Criar"]').css('visibility', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following jQuery selector will work for you:

```
$('span.ms-RadioText[title="Created / Criar"]')
```

By combining it with jQuery's [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function as follows, you should get what you expect:

```
$('span.ms-RadioText[title="Created / Criar"]').hide();
```

Here's a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C7YcV/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector title:

```
.ms-RadioText[title='Created / Criar']
{
  display: none;
}
```

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TFugD/).